# how to edit data stored in the database of Rubymine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubymine

my migration file looks like this:

```
class CreateSages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :sages do |t|
      t.string :Name
      t.string :Email
      t.string :Address
      t.integer :Number
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

My sages table is set up in the database.

Comment: Use AR from the console? Use a client for whatever database you're using?

Comment: What is AR? Can you please elaborate a little?

Comment: ActiveRecord. It means write Ruby code to edit the data. It's not at all clear what you want to do.

Comment: I made a contact form in the view and created the table migration file.Now if i fill the contact form and submit it,the values are stored in the database..but now the question is how to edit them if i want to..now i hope its clear

Comment: Load the record? Please consider doing one of many Rails tutorials, they all cover this.

Comment: thanks buddy for the tym..let me find some tutorial for it :(

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have a class named 'Sage' for 'sages' table.
Try this:

```
 @sage = Sage.find(params[:id])
 @sage.update(params[:sage])
```

`@sage = Sage.find(params[:id])`: This will fetch the record from the database(`params[:id]` should contain the id of the record to be edited).

`@sage.update(params[:sage])`:This will update the record in the database. `params[:sage]` should be hash. Some thing like: `{name: "sage's name", email: "sage's email", address: "sage's address"}`.